# custom validator for checkbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, customvalidator

i have used custom validator

```
 protected void cvIsActive_ServerValidate(object source,ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            if(args.Value.Length==1)
                args.IsValid = true;
            else
                args.IsValid = false;
        }
```

this is code for server validate.. i have written to check whether its checked or not.
i have taken control to validate as checkbox

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Select Status" 
            ID="cvIsActive" Font-Size="Smaller" 
            onservervalidate="cvIsActive_ServerValidate" ControlToValidate="chkIsActive"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

but as soon as page loads it giving error

```
Control 'chkIsActive' referenced by the ControlToValidate property of 'cvIsActive' cannot be validated.
```

Comment: A more robust answer can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/q/1228112/1066291. They are using it to make the checkbox required but you could write any custom validation logic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to set ControlToValidate property for [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx#Y8282) when using it with CheckBox and simply use this in Server Validate like:

```
 args.IsValid = chkIsActive.Checked;
```