# How to create a function that calls a ClientValidationFunction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Is this possible to do this in Javascript and how?

```
function MyClick(){
ValidateTime(sender, args);  // what is the right way to call it?
}

function ValidateTime(sender, args) { //sender and args;these arguments are from a validator control
}
```

I need for MyClick to call that `ClientValidationFunction(ValidateTime)`.

Comment: Where is the definition of the `ClientValidationFunction()` function? Within your `MyClick()` when you call `ValidateTime()` you'd need to set the arguments to variables/values that are actually available at the time, but we can't advise you what they should be because you've shown an empty `ValidateTime()` definition that doesn't make it clear what the arguments are for.

Comment: I want to  use a checkbox to call the the ValidateTime function:
   <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="Chkrnight" onclick="javascript:MyClick();"  />

Comment: It is an attribution inside <cc1:MaskedEditValidator  ClientValidationFunction="ValidateTime" ID="EndTimeTextBoxMaskedEditValidator" runat="server" </cc1:MaskedEditValidator>

Comment: function ValidateTime(sender, args) {args.isValid = true;
                    errorValidator.isvalid = true;}
I am only using the args to check if the control that this control is validating is being fill. Right now for this sample I am just setting it up to true all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments are passed automatically to your `ClientValidationFunction`, you just have to define it with two parameters:

a validator:

```
<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1"
       ClientValidationFunction="ValidateTime"
       .....
       runat="server"/>
```

Here's the function

```
<script language="javascript"> 
   function ValidateTime(sender, args)
   {
        if (bla...){
            arguments.IsValid = true;
        } else {
            arguments.IsValid = false;
        }
   }
</script>
```

If you want to use the validation function from elsewhere i would extract the main logic into a separate function which you can use from your button-click handler and the `ClientValidationFunction`.

Comment: I do have a checkbox and I want for the checkbox to call the ValidateTime(sender, args). Right now the ValidateTime is hooked up with a textbox.

Comment: @user2356029: So why don't you use two `CustomValidators`, one for the `TextBox` and one for the `CheckBox` with the same `ClientValidationFunction`. Or you can use one validator for both since the `CustomValidator` is the only validator that allows to omit the `ControlToValidate`.

Comment: Could you exaplain me how can I attach a validator to my checkbox.
  <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="ChkOvernight" />
  <asp:CustomValidator ID="Validator_ChkOvernight" runat="server" 
   ClientValidationFunction ="CheckItem" Display="None" />

Javascript:
         function CheckItem(sender, args) {}

Comment: If you want to validate multiple controls (like your TextBox+CheckBox) with a single `CustomValidator` you have to omit the `ControlToValidate` property. Then you have to get the reference to your controls via javascript in the `ClientValidationFunction`. For example with `var checkbox = document.getElementById("<%=ChkOvernight.ClientID %>");`

Comment: hmmm... good point Tim, but i have more validation going on in my code, it will be a little difficult to manage all of them.
What about trying to create a CustomValidator for my checkbox like you commented.
I tried to use the argument"ControlTovalidate" but it  didn't work.

The function that I am calling from the CustomValidator is not Firing when I check the checkbox... How can I tie this CustomValidator to my checkbox?

Comment: After researching ..a Checkbox CAN'T have a CustomValidator, Does someone know how to do this? thanks

Comment: @user2356029: Every control can use a `CustomValidator` since that's the only validator which doesn't depend on controls at all (it's the only validator that allows to omit the `ControlToValidate`).

Comment: how can I tied my checkbox to a Customvalidatod?

Comment: You don't need to "tie" the `CheckBox`, just use the `CustomValidator` without `ControlToValidate`. Here's an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228112/how-do-i-make-a-checkbox-required-on-an-asp-net-form (however, you don't need `jQuery` as in that answer, just use `document.getElementById('id').checked` as shown above).